# angular confusing between anchor scrolling angular and wildcard routing "**"

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I have a problem in my angular project the anchor scrolling is confused with the wildCard routes this is what i exaclty do in the project
I enabled the anchor angular scrolling this way in the app.module.ts

```
  RouterModule.forRoot(
  [
    {
      path: 'mobileFilter',
      component: MobileFilterComponent,
    },
    {
      path: '',
      loadChildren: () =>
        import('@test/shared/container').then(
          (m) => m.SharedContainerModule
        ),
    },
  ],
  {
    useHash: true,
    anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
    scrollOffset: [0, 64],
  }
),
```

and in the sharedContainer Module i added the wildcard route this way :

```
      RouterModule.forChild([
          {
            path:'', component: ContainerComponent,
            children:[
              {
                path:'',redirectTo:'home', pathMatch:'full'
              },
              {
                path:'home',
                loadChildren: ()=> import('@test/home').then((m)=>m.HomeModule)},
            {
                path: 'page-not-found',
                component: PageNotFoundComponent
            },
            {
                path: '**',
                redirectTo: '/page-not-found'
            },

      ],
```

the problem when i click in anchor hre tag like this `<a href="#etat"></a>` it redirect me to /page-not-found

Answer (score 0):

You can try to pass fragment value like

```
<a [routerLink]="['your','path']" [fragment]="'fragmentString'">Click Here</a>
<a [routerLink]="['your','path']" fragment="fragmentString">Click Here</a>
```